# How To Add In List Array Using Loop I am Getting Error?

Tags: c#

Hi all i am getting only one value in list array it is not adding rows in it.. how to add rows in list array ?

```
for(int a=0;a<_dt.Rows.Count;a++)
{     
    double PW =Convert.ToDouble(_dt.Rows[a]["POWER"]);
    int VOL =Convert.ToInt32(_dt.Rows[a]["VOLTAGE"]);
    double PV = PW * VOL;
    List<double> res = new List<double>();
    res.Add(PV);
}
```

hopes for your suggestions..

Regards,

Comment: can you also show the definition of `res`

Comment: error means i am getting only one value in res it is not adding rows each time it copies the data on the previous one

Comment: @Dirk res is the list array of double type

Comment: `List<double> res = new List<double>();` is the culprit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the result to a List inside the loop, but you must declare it bevor the loop:

```
List<double> res = new List<double>();             
for(int a=0;a<_dt.Rows.Count;a++) {
    double PW =Convert.ToDouble(_dt.Rows[a]["POWER"]);             
    int VOL =Convert.ToInt32(_dt.Rows[a]["VOLTAGE"]);             
    double PV = PW * VOL;             
    res.Add(PV);         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be remaking the list each intteration. While you havent said the error, perhaps this is the root cause of your problem. Make the list (aka res) before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime in the loop you are creating new instance of the List.
Please take it outside the loop.

- Justin Samuel.